# Including the XML declaration in DataTable.WriteXML

Tags: c#, datatable

I need to convert a DataTable into XML string.
I am using the following to convert that:

```
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  tblXml.WriteXml(sw, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
  string result = sw.ToString();
```

I am getting XML string, but the declartion part is not coming.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

How to include that?

Answer (score 1):

Use [XmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx) and `WriteStartDocument()`.

```
XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(outputStream, Encoding.UTF8);
xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
tblXml.WriteXml(xmlWriter);
string result = outputStream.ToString();
```